# Is a new "poor question" close reason needed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The level of "how to" questions is hitting new lows. From [pick a color for me](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36790/how-do-i-un-muddy-color) ([2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/color-suggestion)) ([3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36668/which-red-and-green-colors-look-still-different-when-printed-as-grayscale)) to [teach me app basics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36768/how-do-i-blend-circles-inside-the-banner-or-a-shape-in-illustrator) ([2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36792/how-to-create-a-polygon-from-vertices-edge-in-3ds-max)) to [make up my mind](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/good-printing-effect-for-pattern-packaging-design).

I proposed a new close reason perhaps....

Titled similar to "low quality question" or "basic how to question", with an explanation comment along the lines of:

---

It might be helpful to review [the types of questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which should and should not be asked. Specifically what to [avoid asking](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). **Simple "how to" and "suggestions please" questions are customarily not desirable.**

---

I'm not always the most personable guy, so that comment could probably be made a bit more friendly for new users.

It's good we're getting more questions, but the quality is really, really poor much of the time.

As JohnB pointed out, it [seems to be an issue network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users). Perhaps a new close reason would curtail some of these overly poor questions.

Would this new close reason be helpful?

The point of adding this is more about the auto-comment than actually closing questions quickly. Users seems to notice comments quickly, a specific welcoming comment, directed at improving their question, *may* help.

Comment: lack of effort is a good name

Comment: For what its worth, StackOverflow used to have a "lack of effort" close reason, but it was sacked because people were "abusing" it.  Not sure what the close options here are, but "Unclear what you're asking" might be a good fit (eg. we know that you want to do X, but what part of doing X do you not understand?).

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter Sounds like you need the design equivalent to this:  *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: @cimmanon Yes. We need something which is equivalent to "why isn't this code working?" Great comparison.

Answer (score 9):

I am in two minds.

I share your frustration over really low quality questions lately.

But I also think that having *too easy* close reasons will make us lazy. It will certainly make *me* lazy, and too easy to not ask specifically for what information that is needed; bad questions will automatically go directly into "close: poor question".

It is a nice way of getting rid of annoying questions, but I feel perhaps a little too convenient.

Some of those bad questions *might* hide interesting things, if the OP could expand a little, with a little guidance.

What I do, is ask for more information, preferably I will ask exactly for the info we need. I will give the poor sod a "reasonable time" to better the question. If this does not happen I will happily close it with no further ado. This is what I do with newbies. For people that "should know better" I will vote to close with no personal interference.

Answer (score 7):

We already have ways to interact with this: the downvote button.

Firstly, I'm with Bente on this one—I'm afraid that a too-easy close reason will make us really lazy and scare newcomers away too quickly.

Yes, I agree that the amount of really bad questions is increasing rapidly, and that the quality is incidentally abysmal, but I don't think that warrants a new close reason: this is what the downvote button was made for.

Personally, I try to refrain from downvoting bad posts by new users, instead opting for a personable, welcoming comment inviting them to improve their Q and nudging them towards learning this site's ropes. But if they fail to improve (sufficiently), then a downvote is the way to go.

Comment: It is good to see the down vote button being used a bit more lately, but there's still a trend to up vote every single new user regardless of question quality. Bad questions receiving up votes is an issue as well.

Comment: Actually, @Scott, if that is the case, that any rubbish gets upvotes _because_ the user is new, that is _seriously_ worrying. That, I would say, is a far worse problems. Maybe a meta-post expanding on that would be good.

Comment: It has always been the case here @Benteh. New users are 99% assured of getting an up vote regardless of what they post.

Comment: Huh, @Scott - never observed it consciously, I will have to pay more attention. Not aware of that. I suppose a vote or two does little harm, as long as this misunderstood welcome-ness does not go too far.

Comment: It's customarily just a single vote so it's not a huge problem. And for poor questions/answers I generally just zero it out :)

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter shouldn't upvoted Q's be at the top?

Answer (score 1):

I really feel a "basic software use" close reason is perhaps in order:

[How to export groups to separate PNG files?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37394/how-to-export-groups-to-separate-png-files)

[Make Lines of .EPS Graphic Bolder or Thicker](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37393/make-lines-of-eps-graphic-bolder-or-thicker)

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37395/trying-to-resize-a-the-diameter-of-a-ring-while-maintaing-thickness

[Unable to ungroup objects in Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37389/unable-to-ungroup-objects-in-adobe-illustrator)

[How to separate clusters of different vector objects in a purchased stock image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37386/how-to-separate-clusters-of-different-vector-objects-in-a-purchased-stock-image)

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37376/how-to-combine-two-separate-paths-into-one

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37306/how-to-create-a-circular-selection

[Rounded Polygons in Photoshop CS6](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17052/rounded-polygons-in-photoshop-cs6)

If any of the above have anything to do with design, then I may as well post questions about how to level my desk, sharpen my pencil, or how to read a ruler.

I realize everyone needs to learn. But I question whether GD.SE wants to become the go-to place for the most basic "how to" questions.

These software 101 questions are becoming more and more prevalent and lowering the overall value of the site in my opinion.

**All** of these questions are instantly answered via a Google search (probably *better* answered via the google search than they will be here) or review of the software help files.

[image]